# Node.js working on locahost but not working on LAN

Tags: node.js

I am new in **nodejs**. I have done simple ajax tutorial, its working on **localhost** but not working on **LAN**. I already have installed nodejs on server side. Please help me how to resolve it.

**server.js**

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  console.log('request received');
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello world......');
}).listen(8080, 'lan_ip');
```

**index.html**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://lan_ip:8080/',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonpCallback: "_testcb",
            cache: false,
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#test").append(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('error ' + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
});
```

My file directory like

**wamp_server> nodetutorial**

```
 - server.js 
 - index.html
```

Comment: Do you have a firewall or something blocking 'external' requests?

Comment: @ stUrb other webservice working fine here.

Comment: But also on the 8080 port?

Answer (score 1):

You're somehow getting firewalled off. Your code is perfectly valid.

What you might want to try as a test is this:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  console.log('request received');
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello world......');
}).listen(8080, '0.0.0.0');
```

`0.0.0.0` is a special address which binds to all interfaces -- eg: if you listen on `0.0.0.0:8000` you can accept requests from your localhost, from lan computers, or from public computers (if your computer has a public IP address).